# The Java Script Results not showing in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, web-applications

I wrote a GAS code to check if the employee is **In or Not** in (extracting data from Google sheets).
The console log give me the right answer but When I click on the button the answer doesn't appear at the front end. Can you help me to troubleshoot on where I went wrong?

```
<div>
<script>
 function onStatus(notify) { 
 
 var employee = "John Peter";
 
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();        
 var mainSheet = ss.getSheetByName("MAIN");
 var data = mainSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
 
 
   for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++){
    var row = data[j];
    var mainSheet2 = row[4];
    var mainSheet3 = row[0];
    var status = (mainSheet2 =="IN" && mainSheet3 == employee) ; 
    if (status == true){
      var notify = employee +" You Are In"
      
      return notify;
 
  }
      }
document.getElementById('status').innerHTML= notify;       
      }
     
    </script>
<button onclick="onStatus()">Check Status</button>

 <font color='Green' id="status" ></font>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't put apps script code like that in the frontend. Please read the [client-to-server communication guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication).

Comment: @Diego I've alreayd added the doGet() function to GAS. I get the button on the client side or front end. but if I click on it, nothing happens. I have no idea what is wrong :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google provides a very good [Client-to-Server Communication guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication) that I highly suggest you read to get a better understanding of how this works.

You cannot put apps script code (e.g. `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()`) in your frontend scripts. That code has to be run by the apps script server in the backend and you'll then call it using a  [`google.script.run`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run) call.

#### Code.gs

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
}

function checkStatus() { 
  var employee = "John Peter";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();        
  var mainSheet = ss.getSheetByName("MAIN");
  var data = mainSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++){
    var row = data[j];
    var mainSheet2 = row[4];
    var mainSheet3 = row[0];
    var status = (mainSheet2 =="IN" && mainSheet3 == employee) ; 
    if (status == true){
      return employee + " You Are In";
    }
  }
}
```

#### Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <button onclick="onStatus()">Check Status</button>
      <font color='Green' id="status" ></font>
    </div>

    <script>
      function onStatus() {
        google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(updateStatus) // Send the backend result to updateStatus()
          .checkStatus(); // Call the backend function
      }
  
      function updateStatus(notify) {
        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML= notify;
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It worked :) Just one more question, If I want to run 2 functions in one button click, will this modification work? onclick="onStatus();onStatus2();" ?

Comment: @MuhammedAadhil Yes, but I would recommend you write a separate function to handle that. `function checkStatus() { actionOne(); actionTwo(); }`

Comment: Thank you :) I'm facing another issue after testing your code. It works fine, but when I refresh the status disappears, I want to keep the status visible untill the employee Clock out. Can you please be kind enough to help me :)

Comment: @MuhammedAadhil it is a good practice to post a new question regarding the follow-up modification you want to accomplish so other readers can benefit from both questions.

Comment: @Marios I made another Question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65076424/how-keep-the-status-keep-appearing-on-javascript-function-to-html